# How to exclude access logs from AWS CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

When I enable log streaming from AWS Elastic Beanstalk to CloudWatch I don't want the nginx/access.log to be streamed, only log/web.stdout.log

Is that possible?

I have created a policy in "Identity and Access Management (IAM)" :

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "VisualEditor0",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": "logs:CreateLogStream",
"Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:326272929619:log-group:/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Myweather-env/var/log/web.stdout.log:log-stream:*"
}
]
}
```

But when I go to Elastic Beanstalk and enable "Instance log streaming to CloudWatch Logs", it creates the following log groups:

```
/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Myweather-env/environment-health.log
/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Myweather-env/var/log/eb-engine.log
/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Myweather-env/var/log/eb-hooks.log
/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Myweather-env/var/log/nginx/access.log  <= can that be excluded?
/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Myweather-env/var/log/nginx/error.log  <= same
/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Myweather-env/var/log/web.stdout.log
```

I'm running a Spring Boot application that contains a configuration in ebextensions:

```
option_settings:
- namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
  option_name: StreamLogs
  value: true
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Generally, you would want to check this config file on your instance: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json and there you should see all of these log groups (and thus remove them). Not sure if Beanstalk would re-create it when you make any change in Beanstalk environment though.

Comment: @Caldazar, thank you for your advise. After a good deal of digging I found the file you mention, on my system is /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/env-config.json. But since I can't find a way to set that up from Beanstalk I decided to turn the access log off in nginx - not the preferred solution